# StaticResource with xmlns prefix cannot be found?

Tags: c#, wpf

Given the "partial" xaml below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.SelectTestView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com etc... etc..."
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="566" d:DesignWidth="1160">

<GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="auto">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusTypeName}"
                       Foreground="{Binding StatusTypeName, Converter={StaticResource StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

My Converter class "StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter.cs" is in my "converters" namespace which I have declared above. When I prefix the Static Resource with my xmlns alias I am still getting a warning that

> "Resrouce "StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter" cannot be found".

The code I have added to prefix/resolve my Static Resource looks like this.

```
Foreground="{Binding StatusTypeName, Converter={StaticResource converters:StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter}}"/>
```

Why is this wrong and what do I need to add to qualify the location so that my Converter can be found? The converter code is meant to assist with the transformation of the view which is composed by this xaml.

Thanks.

Comment: I caught the edit you made, Soner, in less than a minute but you had already jumped on it in the 54 seconds since I had posted! How fast are you!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include that:

```
<UserColtrol.Resources>
   <converters:StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter x:Key="statusTypeNameToBrushConverter"/>
</UserColtrol.Resources>
```

And Static Resource is like that:

```
Foreground="{Binding StatusTypeName, Converter={StaticResource statusTypeNameToBrushConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing StaticResource, but you haven't defined any.
You can do it like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.SelectTestView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com etc... etc..."
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="566" d:DesignWidth="1160">
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
           <converters:StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter x:Key="StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

and then you use it like you did first time:

```
Converter={StaticResource StatusTypeNameToBrushConverter}
```

Comment: So does the ResrouceDictionary allow you to add multiple StaticResources?

Comment: @IsaiahNelson Yes. By the way, I have answered the question 15 minutes ago :) FarhadJabiyev

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Indeed you did, which is why you get the accepted answer. In a meeting at the moment, so I am a little slow to keep an eye on my question here. I appreciate the expediency of your answer through.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Dont forget to bump / upvote my question if you thought it was well written, well researched in how I presented it. I always like to know when I am doing something right.